# Handling backpress when activity started from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, onbackpressed

I have a notification which has two buttons in it. So, when a user clicks on this notification (not on the buttons in the notification, directly on the notification) it launches the main screen.

In my main screen, I show a dialogue which gives this same options as shown in the notification.

When the user interacts with the dialogue and then, later on, click on some button in the main screen, it starts a new activity.

And when the user presses the back button from the new activity which was started. It comebacks to the main screen.

Now the problem that I am facing is, when it comes back to the main Activity(Activity 1) it again showes that dialogue, because it is using the same Intent which started the main screen from the notification

I don't want that dialogue to show again as the user has already interacted with that dialogue. How do I handle this?

This is how my onStart looks like.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String action = getIntent.getAction();
    Log.d("MainScreen", "onStart: action " + action);
    if(action.equals(NOTIFICATION_CLICK)){
        showDialogue();
    }
}
```

Comment: save values in sharedPreference

Comment: Is there no other way through the framework?

Comment: not at all  if you want to save it in local cache used static variable(true, false) but these is bad practice. You have to use sharedPreference

Comment: Which method in the main screen did you show the dialog (onCreate, onStart or onResume)?
I guess you showed dialog in onResume. Because when we click back button, onCreate won't be invoked. Did you try to put your dialog showing method within onCreate method?

Comment: @LuongDinh I was calling in onResume, I tried moving it to onStart. However, still showing the dialogue when back is pressed

Comment: oh, when user click back onStart is also invoked. you should try to move it to onCreate or you can update flag in mainActivity, because this instance is not destroyed.  @SaranSankaran

Answer (score 0):

Which method in the main screen did you show the dialog (onCreate, onStart or onResume)?

I guess you showed dialog in onResume. Because when user go to the other activity onStop is invoked. otherwise, clicking back button by user, onstart and onResume is invoked.

My suggest: 
solution 1:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null && isFromNotification()) {
        showDialog()
    }
}
```

solution 2:

```
private boolean isShow;
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (isShow || !isFromNotification()) return;
    Toast.makeText(this, "I love you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    isShow = true;
}
```

But I prefer the solution 1, it's safer because in case android don't have enough memory the hidden activies which be able to be remove.